# CentOS 7 SystemD Script with additional Command

Tags: centos, systemd, init-script

I've created a SystemD Script to manage an application that is set up as follows

```
/usr/lib/systemd/scripts/testsocket

start() {
    // code here
}

stop() {
    // code here
}

restart() {
    stop
    start
}

list() {
    // code here
}

case "$1" in
    start)
        start
    ;;
    stop)
        stop
    ;;
    restart)
        restart
    ;;
    list)
        list
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Usage: {start|stop|restart|list}"
    ;;
esac
```

I'm happy with this this it does everything it needs to and then the SystemD Service Script

```
/usr/lib/systemd/system/testsocket.service

[Unit]
Description=Node.js Socket Application

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/usr/lib/systemd/scripts/foreversocket start
ExecStop=/usr/lib/systemd/scripts/foreversocket stop
RemainAfterExit=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This also works just fine but only for start, stop and restart. How can I adjust this script to accept the list command in my first script? I keep getting

```
Unknown operation 'list'.
```

Comment: Yes that question has the answer to this problem, thanks a bunch, how do I mark this as a duplicate?

Comment: A systemd service unit that wraps a van Smoorenburg `rc` file that wraps `forever` to run node, with `oneshot` and `RemainAfterExit` bodges because of course this ends up with a nutty structure to the service processes that does not match any readiness protocol, seems like a candidate for the [systemd House of Horror](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/systemd-house-of-horror/).  It is not really wise to construct such rickety contraptions.

Comment: @JdeBP you're probably right but I don't know any other way to keep the node app running